# Method gives diffrent output with loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to classify if a number is inbetween two numbers (or the same).
The input is like this:
T (numbers of cases)
a1 (minimal number)
b1 (maximal number)
c1 (number to test)
a2
b2
c2
...

```
path = "path"
with open(path) as f:
    case = f.readline()
    cases = int(case)
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
file = open("output.txt", "w")

def suitable (l, r, s):
    if (l <= s) and (s <= r):
        return ("Yes")
    else:
        return ("No")

for i in range (cases):
    a = (i * 3)
    b = (i * 3) + 1
    c = (i * 3) + 2
    aa = lines[a]
    bb = lines[b]

    cc = lines[c]
    suit = suitable(aa, bb, cc)
    file.write("Case #{}: {} \n".format(i, suit))
```

This code works. But if I test (3, 10, 3) inside the loop, I get „No“ (expected: Yes). But if I test it outside the loop, it works perfectly fine.
What is the problem here? Something with Python?

Comment: `lines` is a string list. `3 < 10` but `"10" < "3"`.

Comment: Your code ensures `cases` is an integer. But it doesn't do the same with `lines`, and so the elements of `lines` are strings. Your test works with integers. But your loop doesn't pass integers into the function.

Comment: Nice Python feature: `if (l <= s) and (s <= r):` can be written as `if l <= s <= r:`.